# May we use "Neither" without "Nor"?

Tags: neither-nor

> I **neither** use whatsapp **nor** facebook

**OR**

> I don't use whatsapp **neither** facebook

Is second example correct?

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples on a dictionary or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not. Here are some online free references that are commonly recognized,Wikipedia, Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary, Collins Dictionary, VOA, Google Ngram.

Comment: @WXJ96163 I searched referenced examples and I understood from my own example is that the "nor" part is taken place by "don't" in second example so correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: No, your second example isn't correct; we don't use _neither_ with the second noun like that, though we can sometimes use _nor_ without _neither. [See here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nor) I would say "I don't use [either] WhatsApp or Facebook."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example isn't correct, but you can use "neither" without "nor", if you are not explicitly naming both alternatives.

For example, if someone asks you, "Do you use Facebook, or Whatsapp?"
you can answer
"I use neither." or "No, neither one."